# Can we change the iteration direction of Array.find?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, sorting

Look at this crazy question... I have an array with 30.000 items, and I have to run something like this over it:

```
const bigArray = [
  { createdAt: 1 },
  { createdAt: 2 },
  { createdAt: 3 },
  // And so on... 30.000
];

const found = bigArray.find(x => x.createdAt > 29950)
```

And the thing here, is that I know that 100% of the time, that element will be in the index 29.950 (approx). Because that array is already sorted by `createdAt` (coming from the backend)

How does `.find` works? Does it iterates starting from the first element? Is there a way to say "I know it's closer to the end... Change your behavior"?

Of course there is the alternative of doing something like:

```
bigArray.reverse()
const prevIndex = bigArray.findIndex(x => x.createdAt <= 29950);
const found = bigArray[prevIndex - 1];
bigArray.reverse()
```

But I'm not sure if that's gonna be actually worst (because of the fact that there we'll also have some multiples unnecessary iterations... I guess).

Who can give me some clues about this?
It's not that I have a bug here... Not even a performance issue (because 30.000 is not that much), but, feels like there should be something there, and I never hear about it in ~16 years working on JavaScript

Thanks so much!

Comment: I might suggest a binary search approach if you know the values are going to be sorted. You can find the point you're looking for in a few iterations

Comment: @mhodges but there is no native binary search on JavaScript, so, I wonder if creating a function to do the binary search will be faster than the native `.find`. Anyways, I'm not looking for alternatives. Just thinking about "can we change the `.find` behavior?"

Comment: If you want to know how it works you could look at [the spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.prototype.find) and/or the [source code of a particular js implementation](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/objects/js-array.h).

Comment: @BrodaNoel No, you can't change the `.find` behavior. However, implementing a basic Binary search algorithm should net you `O(log n)` (*if your data is sorted*) which will always be faster than `.find` which is `O(n)`. If you know it's going to be toward the end of the array, then you could simply slice your data to work on a small subset first and then if it's not found fall back and search the entire data set? You could also implement your own "findLast" function that would simply `for (let i = arr.length -1; i >= 0; i--)` and work backward through the array, which is also `O(n)` at worst

Answer (score 3):

Based upon the [documentation here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.prototype.find), it appears that `find` is `O(n)` time complexity, where `n` is length of the array.

Since your elements are sorted, you can try to do binary search and reduce time complexity to `O(log n)`.

This is the basic binary search iterative algorithm:

```
function binarySearchIterative (nums, target) {
    let res = -1;
    let left = 0;
    let right = nums.length;
    while (left <= right && res === -1) {
        const mid = Math.floor(left + (right - left)/2);
        if (nums[mid] === target) {
            res = mid;
        }
        else if (nums[mid] > target) {
            right--;
        }
        else {
            left++;
        }
    }
    return res;
};
```

Comment: I don't want to reduce time and complexity. My question is not "how to do it faster?", my question is: "Can we change the iteration direction of Array.find?". I don't want it faster, I just want to KNOW if there is a way to change the iteration direction of Array.find.

Comment: From the documentation link, it reads: `find calls predicate once for each element of the array, in ascending order, until it finds one where predicate returns true.`. Thus, it appears that the direction is from index 0 up to the end of the array. It does not appear to take any parameter to allow traversing from end to index 0.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any options for Array.prototype.findIndex that start from the end... I do know for sure that using Array.prototype.reverse is very expensive and you could make your own algorithm like this if you know that you're likely to find the result you need near the end:

```
const bigArray = [
  { createdAt: 1 },
  { createdAt: 2 },
  { createdAt: 3 }
];

// Add the function to Array.prototype
Array.prototype.findIndexFromEnd = function (cond) {
    for(let i = this.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(cond(this[i])) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

// Gives 1 as expected
console.log(bigArray.findIndexFromEnd(x => x.createdAt == 2));

// Or use an external function if you don't want to edit the prototype
function findIndexFromEnd(array, cond) {
    for(let i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(cond(array[i])) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

// Gives 1 as expected
console.log(findIndexFromEnd(bigArray, (x) => x.createdAt == 2));
```